# Objective-C datatypes and HTTP stream header contents?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, types

I am trying to read out some values from response headers from a Shoutcast stream.

In the following code, what datatypes should my variables be when reading the values?

```
*datatype* header = CFReadStreamCopyProperty(stream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader);   

*datatype* varname = CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields(header);
```

**EDIT:**

Using Jacob Relkin's answer, I get the following warning on the first line

> initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

and the following warnings from the second line

> passing argument 1 of 'CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields' from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFHTTPMessageRef` and `CFDictionary *` (which is toll-free bridged to `NSDictionary`)

Comment: Why am I getting an error about CFDictionary being undeclared?

Comment: @Moshe, I don't know. Try casting it to an `NSDictionary`.